# Best approach for Looped Multi-Curl Request PHP

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

Hi guys I am making a tool which will fetch telephone numbers from the database and make a curl/api request to validate the number and get it's info then update certain fields in the database based from the API response.

So I have a table called `phones` which has

```
->id
->number
->network
->country
```

So in my table only the `id` and `number` which has values, `network` and `country` is null. Which is the reason I will use API that will update those fields depending on the number. However there's a problem, so basically what will happen is I will loop on all those numbers like so:

```
$phone = Phone::all();
foreach ($phone as $key => $value) 
{
  // Call the API that will get the details in the current number
  // and update the details in the table for the current number 

  /** Some code for API Call **/

  //Update Script
  $update = Phone::find($value->id);
  $update->network = $network;
  $update->country = $country;
  $update->country_prefix = $country_prefix;
  $update->status = $status;
  $update->remarks = $remarks;
  $update->save();
}
```

That will work fine and do my task, but problem is this is very slow when I looped in let's say, 50,000 records, coz before it can send the next curl request, it must wait for the response of the previous one right? Question is how can I make it a 20 request per loop count? Coz the API I'm using supports 20 request per second so I wan't to maximize it.

I know my loop will change coz I need to get 20 records at a time and not repeating the same records again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy with a library like [GuzzleHttp](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle). I don't know what your object structure or validation routine looks like, but this example should get you started:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://example.com/api/']);

$updates = [];
$phone = Phone::all();
foreach ($phone as $key => $value)
{

    $update = Phone::find($value->id);
    $update->network = $network;
    $update->country = $country;
    $update->country_prefix = $country_prefix;
    $update->status = $status;
    $update->remarks = $remarks;

    // Load updates into array for processing
    $updates[$update->id] = $update;

    if (count($updates) == 20) {

        // Setting up the async requests
        $promises = [];

        foreach ($updates as $u) {
            // This is posting to http://example.com/api/phone, appending to the 'base_uri' above.
            // This will send a json body, but you can change the format as necessary
            $promises[$u->id] = $client->postAsync('/phone', ['json' => ['phone' => $u->number]]);
        }

        // Waits for the requests to complete
        $results = Promise\unwrap($promises);

        // Saves each number with a 200 response
        foreach ($results as $id => $result) {
            if ($result->getStatusCode() == 200) {
                $updates[$id]->save();
            }
        }

        // Clear processed records from array
        $updates = [];
    }
}
```

You can read through the [documentation](https://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests) for more details.

You can also do this with [`curl_multi_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php), but the implementation is much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

If the API, which you are using, can process more than one number per call then you can request the details of mobile number in bulk instead of sending one by one.
Bulk request for detail will reduce the cost in request/response cycle.

Comment: Yes that what I want to do. But I don't know where to start

Comment: No problem, this snippet will help you to start with,

Comment: $phone = Phone::all();
foreach ($phone as $key => $value) 
{
  // Call the API that will get the details in the current number
  // and update the details in the table for the current number 

  /** Some code for API Call **/

  //Update Script
  $update = Phone::find($value->id);
  $update->network = $network;
  $update->country = $country;
  $update->country_prefix = $country_prefix;
  $update->status = $status;
  $update->remarks = $remarks;
  $update->save();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$phone = Phone::all();
$counter=0;
$some_threshold=100; 
$requestArray = array();
foreach ($phone as $key => $value) 
{
    $requestArray[] = $value;
    if($counter >= $some_threshold)
    {
          // Call the API that will get the details in the  numbers in $requestArray 
          foreach($response as $result)
          {
              $update = Phone::find($value->id);
              $update->network = $network;
              $update->country = $country;
              $update->country_prefix = $country_prefix;
              $update->status = $status;
              $update->remarks = $remarks;
              $update->save();
          }
         $counter=0;
         $requestArray = array();
    }
}
```